# java how to create an object of any class

Tags: java, class, object

I'm working on a method that takes `Class` as parameter and return an Object with different `constructors` of this `Class`

```
public Object getObject(Class c) {
   // I want a code that return new object of this class 
}
```

Is there any think I can do ! 
Thanks..

Comment: Check out reflection, e.g. at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: @Maroun Maroun could you help me please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Class#newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

```
public Object getObject(Class c) {
   return c.newInstance();
}
```

If you want to create a new instance from a custom constructor, you can use for example:

```
public Object getObject(Class c) {
   return c.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors(new class[]{Long.class, 
                       int.class}).newInstance(new Long(6), 4);
}
```

Comment: theres no method `clone()` inside the class `Class` !!!

Comment: Okay thanks, but it throws an error if theres no empty or default constructor , what if I need to return an object with specific constructor ?

Comment: @Sam `c.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors(whateverArgs).newInstance(args);`.. For example: `c.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors(new class[]{Long.class, int.class}).newInstance(new Long(6), 4);`